# Makefile: Silence/hide partial recipe of a rule from the output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
CB_RED := $$(echo "\e[1;41m")
CB_LIGHT_CYAN := $$(echo "\e[1;106m")
C_END := $$(echo "\e[0m")

PRINT_BUILDING = echo $(CB_LIGHT_CYAN)Building $@$(C_END)
PRINT_BUILDING_FAILED = echo $(CB_RED)Building of $@ failed!$(C_END)

foo.txt:
    @$(PRINT_BUILDING)
    touch foo.txt || ($(PRINT_BUILDING_FAILED) && exit 1)
```

Output:
[image]

How can I hide `|| (echo $(echo "\e[1;41m")Building of foo.txt failed!$(echo "\e[0m") && exit 1)` from the output without hiding `touch foo.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  You could do something like this:

```
foo.txt:
        @$(PRINT_BUILDING)
        @echo 'touch foo.txt'
        @touch foo.txt || ($(PRINT_BUILDING_FAILED) && exit 1)
```

You can bundle this up into a function like this:

```
CHECKCMD = @echo '$1'; $1 || ($(PRINT_BUILDING_FAILED) && exit 1)

foo.txt:
        @$(PRINT_BUILDING)
        $(call CHECKCMD, touch foo.txt)
```

One thing to be careful of, if the command contains commas this won't work; you'll have to do something like this:

```
foo.txt:
        @$(PRINT_BUILDING)
        $(call CHECKCMD, (touch foo.txt,bar.txt))
```

(I didn't test this but I think it will work)